# MQL4 make this macd detect divergence

Tags: mql4, indicator, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I would like to make his macd detect divergence and draw lines and arrow on indicator can somebody help?

```
#include <MovingAverages.mqh>

#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 4

input int InpFastEMA = 12;
input int InpSlowEMA = 26;
input int InpSignalSMA = 9;
input int InpWidth = 2;

double ExtMacdBufferRed[];
double ExtMacdBufferMaroon[];
double ExtMacdBufferGreen[];
double ExtMacdBufferLime[];

int OnInit( void )
{
        SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_HISTOGRAM, STYLE_SOLID, InpWidth, Red );
        SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_HISTOGRAM, STYLE_SOLID, InpWidth, Maroon );
        SetIndexStyle( 2, DRAW_HISTOGRAM, STYLE_SOLID, InpWidth, Green );
        SetIndexStyle( 3, DRAW_HISTOGRAM, STYLE_SOLID, InpWidth, Lime );

        SetIndexBuffer( 0, ExtMacdBufferRed );
        SetIndexBuffer( 1, ExtMacdBufferMaroon );
        SetIndexBuffer( 2, ExtMacdBufferGreen );
        SetIndexBuffer( 3, ExtMacdBufferLime );

        IndicatorShortName( "MACD 4C" );

        return INIT_SUCCEEDED;
}

int OnCalculate
(
        const int rates_total,
        const int prev_calculated,
        const datetime& time[],
        const double& open[],
        const double& high[],
        const double& low[],
        const double& close[],
        const long& tick_volume[],
        const long& volume[],
        const int& spread[]
)
{
        int limit, i;

        if( rates_total <= InpSignalSMA )
        {
                return 0;
        }

        limit = ( rates_total - prev_calculated );

        if( prev_calculated > 0 )
        {
                limit++;
        }

        double prevVal = 0;

        for( i = 0; i < limit; i++ )
        {
                double fastMa = iMA( NULL, 0, InpFastEMA, 0, MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE, i );
                double slowMa = iMA( NULL, 0, InpSlowEMA, 0, MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE, i );

                double currVal = ( fastMa - slowMa );
                //Alert("Fast iMA: ", fastMa);
                //Alert("Slow iMA: ", slowMa);
                if( currVal > 0 )
                {
                        if( currVal > prevVal )
                        {
                                ExtMacdBufferGreen[i] = currVal;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                ExtMacdBufferLime[i] = currVal;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        if( currVal < prevVal )
                        {
                                ExtMacdBufferRed[i] = currVal;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                ExtMacdBufferMaroon[i] = currVal;
                        }
                }

                prevVal = currVal;
        }

        return rates_total;
}
```

Comment: what kind of help do you need? And why MQL5 is among the tags?

Comment: I need to make this indicator detect divergences between macd and price, divergences happens when oscilador makes a higher low or high but price makes the opposite.

Comment: ok, so what's the problem? add your piece of code showing how you try to solve the issue and what problems you have with it. If you expect us to code for you, there's plenty of freelance marketplaces who will do that

Comment: I can't find anything on mql4 documentation about how to compare price with oscilator